# Why do the kingdoms need the 4 heroes, if there are adventurers with levels higher than them?

Tags: the-rising-of-the-shield-hero

Supposedly, the kingdoms need the heroes to fight the waves. But there are adventurers with levels higher than them. For example, the shield hero is below level 40 after the two first waves, but the two adventurers he meets later are 52 and 56.

So why do they need the four heroes if there are adventurers stronger than them?

Comment: Not writing as an answer because it's been ages and I don't remember the details, but I'm pretty sure there's some mention of the legendary heroes having a particular immunity to the effects of the waves that normal adventurers don't have.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that while some adventurers are higher level, heroes gain level at a fast pace and have a higher final cap in their level and skill.

For example, the difference is if you played an RPG game for a couple of years and got stuck due to lack of OP weapons, then you will always be around that and it is much harder and slower to improve, but if you were given the most OP weapons in the game off spawn, not only would you progress so much faster, you would also be able to beat the stage that you got stuck at because of the insanely OP weapons.

Remember, the 4 weapons are considered some of the strongest.